# gdb installation with errors -2147414007

Tags: gdb

I'm installing gdb. I'm found this link "https://medium.com/@royalstream/how-to-install-and-codesign-gdb-on-os-x-el-capitan-aab3d1172e95" to install GDB

I don't know why but when i creat this certificat i get the error "-2147414007"

I found nothing about this return on google. Some one got the same error?

[image]
thx :)

Comment: I got this exact problem. I tried creating the certificate in login instead, then exporting it into system. However, I still get the `Unable to find Mach task port for process-id` error message even after I codesign. By the way, you can get past this using sudo gdb instead, but then you will run into a [second, separate problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001329/gdb-doesnt-work-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-3), if you are using gdb 8.1.

Comment: [another thread elsewhere](https://gist.github.com/gravitylow/fb595186ce6068537a6e9da6d8b5b96d) with many people with the same issue.