# Using gdb on macOS High Sierra 10.13.12

Tags: macos, gdb

I'm getting this error when I try running a program using `gdb`.

```
    (gdb) run
      Starting program: /Users/vp/personal/a.out 
      [New Thread 0x1803 of process 3676]
      [New Thread 0x1b03 of process 3676]
      During startup program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
     (gdb)
```

Anybody have any ideas regarding the message?

Comment: Do you actually have an executable installed at `/hello`?

Comment: No, I don't. Fixed

Comment: http://www.owsiak.org/running-gdb-in-macos-sierra/

Comment: @mko didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gdb doesn't work on macos High Sierra 10.13.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001329/gdb-doesnt-work-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-3)

Comment: @ks1322 Yeah, looks like it is. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this on my system running on High Sierra was that the file `.gdbinit` was not found. I was using Eclipse C/C++ as a code editor. In the debug configuration under "Debugger" the path to the `.gdbinit` must be specified, e.g. `/Users/john/.gdbinit`. Then gdb with Eclipse works.

In addition the instructions for using [gdb 8.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001329/gdb-doesnt-work-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-3) must be used.