# The gdb can't work

Tags: c++, gdb

When I use the gdb, it can't work as fllow:(gdb) break 73

```
Breakpoint 2 at 0x100000f35: file a.cpp, line 73.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/caochenglong/Documents/pro/acm/nowcoder/a.o
[New Thread 0x180b of process 25344]
[New Thread 0x2503 of process 25344]
During startup program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
(gdb) q
```

How to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: How do you created executable ? I hope you did correctly. run first `g++ -g test.cpp` and then run `gdb  a.out  -q` and then do `run` inside `gdb`

Comment: Are you sure that `a.o` is an executable file and not an object file?

Comment: If you are on mac, then this is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49001329/72178.