# Strange GDB behavior on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, gdb

I am trying to get `gdb` to work on macOS.  I followed the instructions [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin), and now no longer receive an error regarding the Code Signature.

However, when I try to use `gdb`, I consistently observe the following behavior.

1. I compile a `hello.cpp` file with `g++ -g -o hello hello.cpp`
2. I run `gdb` in the directory where I compiled the file.
3. I enter `file hello` into the `(gdb)` prompt.
4. I enter `break main`.
5. I enter `run`.

GDB now prints out

```
Starting program: (CWD)/hello
[New Thread 0xXXXXX of process DDDDD]
```

where

`(CWD)` is the current working directory (where the executable lives)

`XXXXX` is some hexadecimal number and

`DDDDD` is another number.

From here on, all I seem to be able to do is kill the terminal tab.  Neither `Ctrl-C`, `Ctrl-D` nor anything else I enter seems to have any effect.

### Some Details:

- I installed `gdb` using home-brew, the installed version is 8.2.1
- I did `echo set startup-with-shell off >> ~/.gdbinit`
- The same happens when using the built-in Terminal or iTerm2
- `lldb` works on the same executable

### hello.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello, world" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gdb doesn't work on macos High Sierra 10.13.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001329/gdb-doesnt-work-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-3)

Comment: There is evidence suggesting the latest builds of gdb don't work on macOS. I believe downgrading to 8.0.1 (by following this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49104154/9238288 answer) will solve your issue.