# subject: cannot codesign system certificate for gdb in keychain access in Mac OS X High Sierra

Tags: macos, gdb, homebrew, keychain, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to use gdb on Mac OSX High Sierra. I installed version 8.01 using brew (the latest version 8.1 actually [has a separate, unrelated error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001329/gdb-doesnt-work-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-3)), and am having trouble with the codesign step. I'm following the [instructions at the page suggested by brew](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin).

In Keychain Access, I create a certificate, using the "codesign" option, and overriding defaults, and click through until it asks for the location of the certificate, for which I select "keychain: system". However, immediately afterwards I get a mysterious message:

```
An Error Occurred
Unknown Error = -2,147,414,007
```

This message [also occurred in a previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629275/gdb-installation-with-errors-2147414007), but the sole answer was of low quality, didn't work, and the question didn't seem to be getting much activity/attention. I also tried going into recovery mode and doing `csrutil disable`, but I'm still getting the `-2,147,414,007` error.  Back in the Keychain Access window, under "System", I get the public and private RSA keys of the certificate I just created, but the certificate itself is not there.

If I repeat all that but create under "Login" instead of "System", and this time the certificate gets created. I then export to a .cer file to my desktop, then import back into Keychains, but under the "System" category. I then restart my computer, then do

```
codesign -s gdb-cert /usr/local/Cellar/gdb/8.0.1/bin/gdb
```

but I get `error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.`.

I can of course just do `sudo gdb` or `lldb` with no problem, but I would like to use `gdb` with `emacs`, so those are not options (of course, technically I can just do `sudo emacs` and it will work, but for obvious reasons I prefer not to use `sudo`). How can I codesign gdb so that I can use it without getting `mach port` complaints?

edit: it appears [another thread elsewhere](https://gist.github.com/gravitylow/fb595186ce6068537a6e9da6d8b5b96d) has many people with the same problem. There doesn't appear to be a definitive fix there; I tried some of the suggestions and am continuing to get

```
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 575: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
 (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

Comment: I find that `sudo gdb` can hang where just `gdb` with a properly-signed certificate is OK. Depends on the actual release of `gdb` (and, possibly, on the release of `gcc` used to build it). Undoubtedly because none of the regular GDB maintainers use macOS (see the middle of [this comment](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22960#c6)).

Comment: I am using High Sierra and I have tried to codesign many times to no avail. After acknowledging that this is part and parcel of the llvm takeover of MacOS, I installed an Ubuntu VM on VirtualBox to debug my code. The interface to lldb seems to primitive and foreign to me so I have moved away from trying to run gdb on the Mac ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work. I'm using the latest High Sierra as of the date of this post. First, I installed an older version of gdb, 8.0.1, instead of the latest 8.1,  [which seems to be broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001329/gdb-doesnt-work-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-3):

`brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/9ec9fb27a33698fc7636afce5c1c16787e9ce3f3/Formula/gdb.rb`

then `brew pin gdb`.

For the next steps, I found [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309017/unknown-error-2-147-414-007-on-creating-certificate-with-certificate-assist), and [this other thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302866/keychain-access-error-when-creating-new-system-certificate) useful. Also, [this page](https://gist.github.com/gravitylow/fb595186ce6068537a6e9da6d8b5b96d).

Make the certificate in Login instead of System in order to avoid the `-2,147,414,007` error. Then, click the padlock to unlock the System category, and drag the certificate and keys into System. If anything goes wrong here, you can try File->Import and File->Export instead. The goal is to get the following:

[image: Keychain access]

e.g. the certificate and the keys all under the `System` keychain, not `login`. (It may not even be necessary to drag the keys into system, but I did it just to be safe).

Then, a very important step: right click the certificate, go to Info, Trust, and select Always trust for every category. If you don't do this,  the codesigning will not be effective, and will still get the mach port error message in gdb, even if you codesign.

(One of the answers in the two threads linked above says to temporarily enable the root account in Directory Utilities, but I'm not sure if that's actually necessary). Then, either restart your computer or do `sudo killall taskgated`. Then `codesign -fs gdb-cert $(which gdb)`.

Then, I no longer got the mach port error message in gdb. The first time I ran, I got [a popup asking for a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132826/stop-developer-tools-access-needs-to-take-control-of-another-process-for-debugg#9725547). To disable it for future runs, I did `sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity --enable` as per that thread.

Note also that 8.0.1 has a minor issue: you will get warnings about `unhandled dlyd version`. That's explained in [this thread](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/20047). Note some posts in that thread say breakpoints don't work, but I didn't see that happening.

Comment: The instructions I used are [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Codesigning-the-Debugger.html). Note the last sentence (need to be in Unix group `_developer`).

Comment: This almost worked for me on MacOS 11.2.3, Darwin 20.3.0, gdb 10.1 under Homebrew 3.1.1. At least it got me past the codesigning part. I think avoiding the  -2,147,414,007 error and the `sudo killall taskgated` was the things that made a difference. BTW on MacOS 11.2.3 you can't drag'n'drop the certificate to System, but copy and paste worked. I also deleted the copy in the login chain, don't know if that is necessary.

Now to research `../../gdb/target.c:2149: internal-error: void target_mourn_inferior(ptid_t): Assertion `ptid == inferior_ptid' failed.`. Being on an M1 might be a problem.

Comment: Actually that was [this GDB bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26861) which is in the 10.2 code base. Planned release in June, bummer... `lldb` it will have to be until then.